# Sql alchemy bind column name as parameter

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I would like to execute a raw sql query using sql alchemy core where the column name is a dynamic parameter. In example:

```
db_conn.execute(text("Select * from users where :field = :val"), field ='user_id', val=1)
```

But I figured out that the field name parameter doesn't work that way...

Any ideas?

Comment: What o/p you are getting ? any error ?

Comment: Not getting any errors, it just returns no results as it compiled into the following query:

`Select * from users where 'user_id' = 1)`

Comment: Does it returns when you gives directly the field name and variable instead of dynamic parameter ?

Comment: Yes @VikasDamodar, also when using only dynamic parameter

Comment: You cannot pass identifiers using placeholders. Either whitelist and format, or use `column()` constructs: `select(['*']).select_from(table("users")).where(column("user_id") == 1)`.

Comment: Why not use table metadata instead? SQLAlchemy can generate any SQL construct for you, and you can use `metadata['tablename'].c[field]` to access a column; this guarantees that the column exists and you close the door on SQL injection. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html; you can load this from an existing database using [reflection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html). See [sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error](//stackoverflow.com/a/25387570) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to pass identifiers as params into text construct.

More info here:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text